# Stack Overflows Internacionais: ilimitado, atual e completo em seu idioma nativo

Tags: debate

Traduzido de [International Stack Overflows: Unlimited, On Time, and Comprehensive in your native language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/369699), por Nicolas Chabanovsky♦

> TL;DR
>
> Pessoas perguntaram: "Qual é a missão dos nossos sites internacionais?
>   que problemas eles resolvem?" A resposta: "Eles são como o Stack
>   Overflow em Inglês, apenas em um idioma diferente" torna os sites
>   internacionais ainda mais misteriosos. Pensamos que seria ótimo
>   dissipar a névoa do mistério adicionando um artigo na central de ajuda
>   sobre a missão desses sites internacionais. Por favor, dê uma olhada
>   em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto e diga-nos o que acha.
>   Os moderadores podem editar e iríamos gostar se ajudasse-nos a
>   traduzir.

Por favor, deixe-me dizer algumas coisas por trás dessa missão. Para começar, pense na diferença entre um desenvolvedor nativo que fala inglês e um desenvolvedor não fala inglês. Como essa diferença afeta suas vidas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>(Encontrei essa imagem no [Google Images](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/styles/the_breaking_news_image_style/public/nick-shepherd-illustration-040216.jpg).)</sup>

## O problema dos desenvolvedores que não falam inglês: pouco, tardio e fraco

Se alguém procura por uma resposta em programação em um idioma que não seja o inglês, eles encontrarão links para fóruns parecidos com phpBB, respostas espalhadas em comentários de blogs pessoais, listas de e-mails, etc. A única fonte de informação de qualidade nesse idioma ainda são os livros. Parece que ainda estamos presos em 2007...

Como resultado, existe uma tremenda assimetria na informação disponível em diferentes idiomas. Desenvolvedores em todo o mundo que não fala inglês têm menos informações disponíveis, ou atrasadas  e algumas nuances importantes são perdidas.

O Stack Overflow em inglês impactou desenvolvedores que não falam inglês? Sim, de fato! Nos últimos anos, vimos o surgimento de sites com conteúdo do Stack Overflow auto-traduzido. Pode-se apenas sonhar que tem sido traduções automáticas de qualidade com correções humanas, mas é uma tonelada de conteúdo semelhante a spam, a maioria das quais não faz qualquer sentido para um ser humano. Há uma dúzia desses sites com alguns milhões de páginas geradas em cada um. É isso que nós, desenvolvedores que não falam inglês, vemos nos resultados da pesquisa todos os dias... e isso não é uma piada.

A situação cria uma enorme desigualdade entre os desenvolvedores cuja primeira língua é o inglês e o resto de nós. Para uma grande parte da população mundial, a própria programação é uma grande área cinzenta, o limite para entrar na indústria ainda é alto, aprender programação é muito difícil e caro.

Atualmente, a TI não é bem projetada para pessoas de fora do mundo falante de inglês. Mas, juntos, vamos mudar essa tendência!

## O Objetivo: respostas detalhadas a qualquer questão de programação possível em seu idioma nativo.

Em nosso mundo hoje, duas pessoas com habilidades e paixão semelhantes por programação começam a aprender ao mesmo tempo. Alguns anos depois, ambos irão ao aeroporto para uma conferência no mesmo táxi. No entanto, uma das pessoas (o falante nativo de inglês) será um apresentador na conferência, enquanto o outro (o não-falante de inglês) será o taxista, já que a falta de informação em sua língua nativa tornou quase impossível para eles chegarem ao nível quando eles seriam contratados como desenvolvedor.

Missão e objetivo final dos Stack Overflows internacionais é criar um mundo onde todos tenham oportunidades iguais para serem bem-sucedidos em programação, independentemente de sua língua nativa ou de quaisquer outros preconceitos. Desejamos ter mais carros autônomos e menos motoristas em todo o mundo.

## Solução Stack Overflow: ilimitadas, atuais e completas.

Todo mundo começa igual - com uma forte paixão por ser um desenvolvedor. A única diferença é que alguns de nós têm material abrangente suficiente quando necessário em seu idioma nativo. Outros não. Nós, que não temos, gastamos zilhões de horas extras simplesmente traduzindo, revisando e passando pelo conteúdo muitas vezes, enquanto esclarecemos todas as nuances de uma tecnologia. Se quisermos ser eficazes, precisamos mudar essa tendência. Acreditamos que um bom ponto de partida é a criação de uma coleção bem estruturada de respostas detalhadas a todas as questões de programação e uma comunidade de ajuda mútua.

## Stack Overflow fala muitos idiomas

O Stack Overflow é sobre nós. É sobre todos os desenvolvedores em todo o mundo que desejam ajudar outras pessoas e que estão procurando uma resposta *on-line*, independentemente de quaisquer limites de idioma, sejam eles de programação ou humanos.

Para tornar o tesouro da sabedoria da comunidade disponível para todos, precisamos ter você a bordo! Por favor, junte-se aos nossos Sites Internacionais, faça e responda perguntas, e compartilhe os sites com seus amigos. Diga-lhes porque os Stack Overflows internacionais existem e qual é a sua missão. Sua recomendação é a única maneira pela qual os Sites Internacionais crescerão.

Comment: Já traduzi o manifesto no nosso site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto